# Replace the question marks

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Here's some number problems.

8:2::1:1::64:?

A:4::D:49::?:169

439: SQUARE::125:CUBE::216:?

A:8::M:5::J:1::O:10::M:?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible Answers**
First one

> 8:2::1:1::64:**4**
>  First number is the cube of the second

Second one

> A:4::D:49::**F**:169
>  Take the $n$th prime where $n$ is the position in the alphabet of the letter and square it (i.e, $A=2^2, B=3^2, C=5^2,\ldots$)

Third one

> 439: SQUARE::125:CUBE::216:**SQUARE**
>  Take the sum of the digits. If it's a square, then SQUARE. Otherwise, if it's a cube then CUBE. 2+1+6=9 which is a SQUARE.

Fourth one (spotted by @Stiv)

> A:8::M:5::J:1::O:10::M:**3**
>  Each letter is the first letter of a month with 31 days and the number is its position in the calendar. Since May has appeared already, the next must be March, which is the 3rd month.

Comment: Yes, you are correct on the first three. The last one is tricky though.

Comment: I suspect rot13(Z jvyy or 3, fvapr gurer ner zbaguf bs gur lrne ortvaavat jvgu nyy bs gurfr yrggref pbeerfcbaqvat gb gurve cbfvgvba va gur lrne va grezf bs zbagu ahzore 1-12. Gur bayl bgure bar ortvaavat jvgu Z vf Znepu va cbfvgvba 3.) Can't spot if there's a particular sub-sequence involved here though...

Comment: @Stiv Ah I see but you must be right.